Concatenation of $f$-related vector fields/tangent vectors
This is probably a highly trivial question, but I just can't wrap my head around it. Let $M,N$ be two manifolds and $f: M \rightarrow N$ smooth. Let further $X^1, X^2$ be two smooth vector fields on $M$ and $Y^1, Y^2$ on $N$. Further, $Y^i$ is $f$-related to $X^i$, that is
for all $p \in M$:
$$Y^i_{f(p)} = D_pf(X^i_p).$$
Let $g \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty} (N)$. Now, what exactly does the following concatenation (which is for example encountered in Lie brackets) mean?
$$Y^1_{f(p)}(Y^2_{f(p)}(g))$$
If I try to "unwrap" it in terms of $X$ I always end up with ill-defined expressions:
$$Y^1_{f(p)}(Y^2_{f(p)}(g)) = D_pf(X^1_p)(D_pf(X^2_p)(g)) \\
= D_pf(X^1_p)(X^2_p(g \circ f)) \\
= X^1_p(X^2_p(g \circ f)\circ f).$$
The problem is that $D_pf(X^i_p)(\cdot)$ expects some $g \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty} (N)$. I understand that $X^2_p(g \circ f)$ is to be understood as $g \mapsto X^2_p(g \circ f)$, but how can this be concatenated again with $f$? In what sense is $X^2_p(g \circ f) \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty} (N)$ so that $D_pf(X^1_p)(X^2_p(g \circ f))$ is well-defined?

So I found the problem. The concatenation encountered in the Lie bracket, is ,in fact, not defined as I did it in my question, but as follows. Let $h \in  \mathcal{C}^\infty (M)$. Then
$$[X^1,X^2]h: p \mapsto X^1_p(X^2h) - X^2_p(X^1h).$$
the inner vector field is not evaluated in $p$, which was the problem. So, considering again only the first term (the original question) and keeping in mind that this inner vector field actually is $(q \mapsto Y^2_qg) \in \mathcal{C}^\infty (N)$, we can write
$$Y^1_q(\tilde q \mapsto Y^2_{\tilde q}g) = X_p^1(\tilde p \mapsto Y^2_{f(\tilde p)}g) = X_p^1(\tilde p \mapsto X^2_{\tilde p}(g \circ f))$$
Again, the important point is that the concatenation due to the $f$-relation of $Y^1$ to $X^1$ has to appear in the index of $Y^2$. Now everything should be well-defined.

I think instead of $(q \rightarrow Y^{2}{q}h)$ it should be $(q \rightarrow Y^{2}{q}g)$. Otherwise $Y^{i}$ acts on something not within its domain.

Yes, you're of course right! That was a typo from copy-pasting. I've edited the post and corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out!
